# Broken stylesheet and image paths when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, static, asset-pipeline

I've deployed a fresh Rails 4 app to Heroku but my stylesheets and images don't work. For the stylesheets. I use:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "screen", media: "all" %>
```

For image, I use paths encoded in CSS, like:

```
<img class="logo small" src="/assets/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
```

These paths work perfectly well on my local machine but break in deployment. I thought that this is due to the not serving of static assets by the Heroku Cedar stack, and set this setting to `true` in production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

This didn't solve it. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out - this issue was due to a badly functioning git repository. I'm using the asset pipeline now for both stylesheets and images - but I had to delete both the local git repository and the remote app and initiate everything from scratch. These are the steps I've taken:

1) Declare all stylesheets in application.css like so:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require frameless
 *= require typography
 *= require grid
 *= require layout
```

(My old app used a `screen.css` file in which I imported the above files. This doesn't work with the AP - every file must be referenced directly in the `application.css` manifest file, in the correct order so as the CSS rules stack up with the right precedence. To ensure this, you might want to delete the `require_tree` directive that is there by default).

2) Change all HTML image paths to rails helper `image_tag` tags.

3) Run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to generate a `public/assets` directory with all the precompiled assets, [as described here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline).

Check everything into a new git repository (having deleted the new), and then follow [Heroku's instructions on how to deploy a Rails 4 app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4).

Bingo!

Comment: goo job - my next question was going to be if you were adding `screen` to the precompile list (which you can do in addition to the default `application` file it adds).

Comment: Yeah, I thought that since I must declare in `application` every file referenced in `screen` anyway, I'll just let that be the "new" import file.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku have specific instructions for hosting Rails4 applications on Heroku. Do you have the `rails_12factor` gem in your Gemfile for production?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems

Also, I would suggest switching to using the rails helpers for images as it makes it easier when dealing with the asset pipeline in production -

```
<%= image_tag 'logo', class: 'logo small'  %>
```

Comment: I do have the ´rails_12factor´ gem declared for the "production" group - and it's picked up by my Gemfile.lock. I was going to switch to rails helpers for images at some point - however the problem doesn't seem to stem from that (the app is still completely unstyled).